# Initializing an expanded array elements

Tags: c++, arrays, function-pointers

So i've been able to learn to expand an array, but was wondering how i would go about adding elements to the expanded space, here is what i have so far.

```
int *expand(int *arr, int size)
{
    int *newArray;


    newArray = new int[size * 2];
    memcpy( newArray, arr, size * sizeof(int));
    for (int index = 5; index < size; index++)
        newArray[index] = 0;
    return newArray;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you might have a bug in your code. newArray is of size "size * 2", but you initialize elements only up until "size".

Try this:

```
newArray = new int[size * 2];
memcpy( newArray, arr, size * sizeof(int));
for (int index = size; index < (size*2); index++)
    newArray[index] = 0;
return newArray;
```

This should initialize all the elements in the new space to 0's.

Comment: So i tried this code with some other things, when i cout i'm not seeing the elements...

Comment: Just tried the code I suggested and it works fine, with elements showing up both inside and outside the function. Not sure what the issue could be.

Comment: @Shamir: It's also worth pointing out, that the expand function is allocating memory (newArray), and not freeing up the source memory (arr), so there's a good chance that this is going to result in a memory leak.  It's generally a good idea to keep memory allocation/freeing at the same level so that it's clear where responsibility for cleanup lies.